# Import after installing with setuptools fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is probably a simple mistake  on my part, but I just can't get this to work.

When I run a simple application which imports a custom package it works fine, but if I install the script + package with setuptools then it seems that the module is not found. I have dumbed this down to a really simple example with the following source structure:

```
.
├── hello
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── message.py
├── hello.py
└── setup.py
```

`hello.py` contains just the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from hello import MESSAGE

print(MESSAGE)
```

and `message.py` contains this:

```
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
```

and `__init__.py` contains:

```
from .message import MESSAGE
```

If I run this from my source tree it works fine:

```
$ ./hello.py 
Hello, World!
```

Now, I try to create an installer using `setuptools` like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "Hello World",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = "Hello World",
    url = "http://www.example.com",
    author = "XX",
    author_email = "XX@YY.ZZ",
    license = "XXX",
    scripts=["hello.py"],
    packages=["hello"]
)
```

I can install as a regular user like this:

```
$ python3 setup.py install --user
```

which puts everything under `$HOME/.local/`. When I try to run `hello.py` from the installed location I get the following error:

```
$ $HOME/.local/bin/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/hello.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('Hello-World==1.0.0', 'hello.py')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1445, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Hello_World-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    __requires__ = 'Hello-World==1.0.0'
  File "/home/XXX/.local/bin/hello.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('Hello-World==1.0.0', 'hello.py')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1445, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Hello_World-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    __requires__ = 'Hello-World==1.0.0'
ImportError: cannot import name 'MESSAGE'
```

So it seems the import can't find the module and `MESSAGE` is not imported.

What did I miss?

And, a second question, why does setup generate an egg rather than a wheel? I thought wheels are the preferred format now.

Some extra info for context:

OS = Linux Mint

Python version = 3.6.9

Comment: Do not use files with the same names as folders/ modules. Either rename `hello.py` or `hello` folder.

Comment: That was it! Now, any recommendations for naming packages like this, where there is a script with the same or name? Lets say I am writing an application xxx and I want to keep the script simple and put all the implementation in a package, what is the recommended package name in that case?

Comment: Personally, I always name the main file (the file that everything begins from) of my program as `main_file.py`. I also try to name folders based on what they contain, like a folder called `constants` that would contain multiple python files with constants in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so as per @BoobyTrap 's comment, the solution was simple. renaming the `hello` directory to `HelloLib` and updating `hello.py` to import with the new name solved the issue.